# Save byte array of image to file

Tags: android

I try below code to get an URL file's thumbnail.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(URL);
byte[] image = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
```

I get the byte array(image) of thumbnail.
And I want to save it as an image file.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this.

```
public void writeToFile(byte[] array) { 
    try { 
        String path = "YOUR_LOCAL_PATH"; 
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path); 
        stream.write(array); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be IOException to catch both FileOutputStream and write()?

Comment: @Davidsun whats the file type in PATH?